# CSS bar graph - very simple

Tags: css, charts

I have some very basic code and it works except everything aligns to the top...ideally the bars would align to the bottom. I suppose I could use fixed positioning as the dimensions are squared at 50px by 50px but I'd prefer something a little less "fixed".

```
      <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaeae; background-color: #eaeaea; width: 50px; height: 50px;">
        <div style="position: relative; bottom: 0; float: left; width: 8px; height: 22px; background-color: #aeaeae; margin: 1px;"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; bottom: 0; float: left; width: 8px; height: 11px; background-color: #aeaeae; margin: 1px;"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; bottom: 0; float: left; width: 8px; height: 6px; background-color: #aeaeae; margin: 1px;"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; bottom: 0; float: left; width: 8px; height: 49px; background-color: #aeaeae; margin: 1px;"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; bottom: 0; float: left; width: 8px; height: 28px; background-color: #aeaeae; margin: 1px;"></div>
      </div>
```

I don't want to use a library or JS add on. Keeping this light weight is mission critical.

Also I'd prefer the bars were vertical. Any CSS guru care to shed the bit of light I seem to be missing? I've googled and most examples are far to complicated/sophisticated,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, separate your CSS from your HTML. You're repeating too much code when you could just use a bar class for your inner divs.

`bottom: 0` doesn't change anything for relatively positioned div.

If you wish to use relative positioning, get rid of float and bottom and use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: baseline;`. Also, in this case, you need to get rid of any space in the HTML between the inner divs (newline).

Like this (you can see the demo at http://dabblet.com/gist/2779082 ):

**HTML**

```
<div class="graph">
        <div style="height: 22px;" class="bar"></div><!--
        --><div style="height: 11px;" class="bar"></div><!--
        --><div style="height: 6px;" class="bar"></div><!--
        --><div style="height: 49px;" class="bar"></div><!--
        --><div style="height: 28px;" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.graph {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.bar {
    width: 8px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kolink's answer is correct. Each bar div's width is 8px, plus margin-left and margin-right, 8+1+1=10px. So I suggest, set the left value to 0px, 10px, 20px ...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style=" left:0px;height:22px;"></div>
    <div style="left:10px;height:11px;"></div>
    <div style="left:20px;height:6px;"></div>
    <div style="left:30px;height:49px;"></div>
    <div style="left:40px;height:28px;"></div>
</div>
```

The css should look like this(I grouped some general css rules):

```
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid #aeaeae; 
  background-color: #eaeaea; 
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px;
  position : relative;

}

.wrapper > div{
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 8px;
  position : absolute;
  background-color: #aeaeae; 
  margin: 1px;
  display : inline-block; 

 }
```

You can check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/zhujy_8833/AFbt4/ to see the result of the above code.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally avoid setting xpos explicitly on every element, makes things less maintainable. In some scenarious percentage-basedvalue dumps would be more appropriate too. With that in mind, an imo more scalable and semanticaly correct approach has been mocked up in a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ovfiddle/6jzxM/). HTML:

```
<ul class="graph">
    <li><span style="height:45%"></span></li>
    <li><span style="height:12%"></span></li>
    <!--as many more items as you want !-->
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
.graph {
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae; background-color: #eaeaea;/*"canvas" styling*/
    float:left; /*should be clearfix'd instead, but this is OK for a demo*/
}
.graph li {
    width:8px; height:50px; /*set a bar width and a full height*/
    float:left; /*to have bars "left-aligned"*/
    position:relative; /*needed for the actual bar fill element*/
    margin:2px;
 }
 .graph li+li {
    margin-left:0; /*avoid margin double-up between bars as they don't collapse*/
 }
 .graph span {
    position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; /*"bottom-align" the bars,
                                                  widths will be set inline*/
    background-color: #aeaeae;
 }
```

This also gives you potential to get quite fancy - bars could have content with a negative text indent for semantic value or `<span>` elements could be abandoned altogether in favor of pseudo-elements.

Comment: Wow sweet. :) Thanks for all the replies...CSS is awesome if you know what your doing :) The demo link above looks awesome and works wonders.

Comment: One remaining question whats with the <!-- --> though? I know their HTML comments and when removed they throw off alignment but why?

Comment: @USER897075: ಠ_ಠ I think you're trying to communicate with Ana, comment removal would not affect the code in my answer. Ana suggested using inline-block rendering for bars meaining that whitespace is rendered - equivalent to that of one ` ` (space symbol) between the bars

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute`, and instead of `float:left;` use `left: 0px;`, `8px`, `16px` and so on.
Also add `position: relative` to the container.

Comment: the part where individual bars have to be repositioned with an explicit `left` value is a bit off-putting

Comment: Setting the divs to inline-block and using the vertical-align property is a more flexible solution. Avoid using absoute positioning if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the parent `position: relative`, then you can use `position: absolute` for child `div` to place them in precise coordinates by setting `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `width`, `height` you can precisely control the placement of the bars in your bar chart.

```css
.graph {
    position: relative;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.bar {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
  <div style="position:absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px; right: 1px; bottom: 1px">
    <div class="bar" style="bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 8px; height: 22px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="bottom: 0; left: 10px; width: 8px; height: 11px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="bottom: 0; left: 20px; width: 8px; height: 6px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="bottom: 0; left: 30px; width: 8px; height: 49px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="bottom: 0; left: 40px; width: 8px; height: 28px"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<p></p>

<div class="graph">
  <div style="position:absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px; right: 1px; bottom: 1px">
    <div class="bar" style="left: 0; top: 0; height: 8px; width: 22px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="left: 0; top: 10px; height: 8px; width: 11px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="left: 0; top: 20px; height: 8px; width: 6px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="left: 0; top: 30px; height: 8px; width: 49px"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="left: 0; top: 40px; height: 8px; width: 28px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```